# `Go to Definition` option is no more visible on my VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am no longer able to see `Go to Definition` option on right click in visual studio code.
Can anyone please tell me what am I missing ??

[image]

Comment: It looks like this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6854).

Comment: @Luuk  the above like is for a C++ project my project is typescript based.

Comment: But both code is in Visual Studio Code, and I think its a problem in that editor/IDE/environment?

Comment: why don't you fix the PROBLEMS first

Comment: @rioV8 I have fixed the problem, as you can see on line 3 I have declared type for the variable to `History` interface.

Comment: you still have 2 PROBLEMS (squiglle), read the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Installing **C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing** extension fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

When working with JS/Typescript, disabling C/C++ extensions (C/C++ and PlatformIO) and reloading VS Code for my workspace helped.